# How to use admin.ModelAdmin and register it into my views in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to use the Admin's search, filter list in my application. Normally we can use them in the Admin site by registering them. But I don't know what to do in my application to use them.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/bartTC/django-frontendadmin is interesting for you as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter). Its much more powerful than the admin filter.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Actually what I need is the Admin site's searching-filtering-paging functions when listing. As I understand, django-filter is just for filtering